# Due to natural rotation of Milky Way all Earth life gets increased intelligence

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story in the late 1970s, perhaps very early 1980s.

All life (with a brain I guess) on Earth suddenly develops increased intelligence. Scientists determine this is due to the normal 250-million-year rotation of the Milky Way. There is some large part of space ("dust cloud"?) that the solar system rotated through (and recently out of) that inhibited brain function in some kind of way. Now that this is no longer the case all higher lifeforms become smarter.

One example given that I have always remembered clearly is about a dog now being smart enough to open a freezer, take out some frozen meat, and then wait for it to thaw before eating it.

Seeing that I read it way back when, I will have read a translated version. So I cannot be certain that the original is in English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Poul Anderson's *[Brain Wave](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1228628.Brain_Wave)*.

> Throughout earth's history, it has been in a region of the galaxy
>   where some sort of force field has inhibited the activity of brain
>   neurons. **As the solar system spins around the galaxy, the earth exits
>   this region, and almost overnight, all living creatures with brains
>   are impacted. Brain neurons fire more rapidly, and as a result, they
>   all become smarter.** Smart people become geniuses, morons become very
>   smart, and animals gain in intelligence as well.
>
> Society turns upside down. People who previously had an inner purpose
>   in life, some aspiration or goal, use their new boost in intelligence
>   to their advantage, and to society's advantage as well. People who
>   previously had no goals, ambitions, or purpose in life have great
>   difficulties--they still retain their old personalities, their
>   superstitions and prejudices, and become despondent or even violent.
>   The story follows several people through these changes; a scientist,
>   his wife, and a low-intelligence farmhand.

Comment: @Richard: I was certain that it was a short story. That would explain why I never found this "short" story. I also should have searched a little longer for already-asked. (I was focussing on the Milky Way rotating bit.) Apologies for that. Wikipedia gives an example of a rabbit escaping a snare, and I remember that as well. It definitely is Poul Anderson's story. Thanks.

Comment: @user14111 - Indeed. And closed as dupe.

Comment: @user14111: Almost. You're just one country off. ;-) I know now why I thought it was a short story. I read it in [this anthology](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?371559).